Menu bar icons are hidden when they take too much space on macOS 14 Sonoma
I never had this problem on macOS 13 Ventura and older versions and now this seems very annoying when using macOS 14 Sonoma.
When there are too many icons in the Menu bar, at some point they are just hidden (even though there is available space).
I noticed this issue when using MenuMeters and setting the "Vertical Bar" option in the CPU preferences (because it takes a lot of space). Initially I thought it was a bug of this application but then figured out that any new icon will not be displayed in the menu bar after a certain amount of space is already taken.

This is how my menu bar looked like in Ventura:

And now in Sonoma any icon would become automatically hidden after a certain length (regardless if there is space afterwards or not).
Users on the web suggest Bartender to mitigate this issue, however it is yet not ideal (and also it is paid software).

Either: Get your Menu Meters usage under control, or use Bartender. Just use Bartender. You have paid for your Mac, now pay for a bit of really useful software. Also iStat Menus is easier on the menubar space.

Do you really need to monitor all 16 cores of your CPU separately all the time? I have Activity Monitor running in the background, and if there's a problem, I'll have a look. By and large, the Mac can look after itself.

@benwiggy not necessarily all 16 but this has been very useful to me for years to monitor how the CPU is loaded (are tasks parallelised or only one or two cores are loaded?)

@Gilby as I said in my question, the main issue with Bartender is NOT that it is a paid software. It just MITIGATES the issue, does not solve it completely. The whole problem starts because of a bug of the new Menu Bar in Sonoma. Without this bug I wouldn't need Bartender at all.

But you can't manage the loading of the cores yourself, so what do you do if the tasks aren't equally loaded? Sorry for tangent, but I've never understood why such monitoring is a good use of my time!

@benwiggy 1) to compare how different applications better scale their tasks on different CPUs instead of overloading only a few of them, so I can choose the best ones 2) I'm a developer myself so it's good to monitor how the software I'm building scales

“The whole problem starts because of a bug of the new Menu Bar in Sonoma. Without this bug I wouldn't need Bartender at all. ” Well, you can wait for Apple to fix the ‘bug’, or get an app like Bartender and address the issue yourself.

@SteveM that's what I'm doing already, but I would like to have a proper solution for this bug

If you don't want to use Bartender, the alternative free option is Hidden Bar.

“… but I would like to have a proper solution for this bug.” Then you’ll need to file a bug report with Apple.

There is a plist key to change the size of the gap between menu items:
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain NSStatusItemSpacing -int #


An alternative strategy to see loading on each core (or thread) is to use Activity Monitor:

To display this:
Control-Click (or right click) on the Activity Monitor's Dock icon, select Monitor > Show CPU Usage.
You might also like > Show CPU History. That is more informative.

